# Are the Dragon Ball Heroes anime and manga supposed to follow the same story?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

After chapter 2 of the manga, and episode 6 of the anime, (after the battle with Cumber to be more precise) Dragon Ball Heroes looks nothing alike, they are fighting different villains. Is it episode 7 of the anime, supposed to be "filler" and Dragon Ball Heroes is going to retake the manga or how it is? Is the Dragon Ball Heroes anime said to be based in the manga or not?

Answer (score 1):

The *Dragon Ball Heroes* anime is promotional material, hence very short and cannot cover all the material present in the manga, As of now, the anime has finished the *Prison Planet Arc* and has now moved on to the *Universal Conflict arc*, which you can read about [here](https://comicbook.com/anime/2019/01/13/dragon-ball-heroes-universal-conflict-synopsis-anime-explain/).